# If $A\subset\mathbb{R^2}$ is countable, is $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus A$ path connected?

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arcwise connected part of $\mathbb R^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155952/arcwise-connected-part-of-mathbb-r2)

As the topic,if $A\subset\mathbb{R^2}$ is countable, does $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus A$ path connected??? I know the answer is it is path connected but not sure how to prove it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Gosh, I just duplicated your answer...

Comment: @did: Well, it *is* the natural thing to do, I think.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a marginal variation:

Choose $x_0,x_1 \in A^c$. Let $d \neq 0$ be orthogonal to $x_1-x_0$. Define the collection of paths $\gamma_\alpha(t) = x_0 + t(x_1-x_0) + \alpha t(1-t) d$. Since $\{\gamma_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in [0,1]}$ is uncountable, there exists $\alpha_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $\gamma_{\alpha_0}[0,1] \cap A = \emptyset$. Hence $A^c$ is path connected.

Comment: How do these paths look like?

Comment: They look like segments of a parabola. It is not hard to generate a little example in the plane.

Comment: Why the downvote after 8 years?

Comment: @abeliangrape: Did you downvote this?

Comment: ?? No, your answer was helpful. Why would I?

Comment: @abeliangrape: Thanks for reply. Someone downvoted after 8 years, I was curious why.

Comment: @copper.hat +1.. can you give me  some reference that how you derive the formula $\gamma_\alpha(t) = x_0 + t(x_1-x_0) + \alpha t(1-t) d$ or tell me some book name where this concept are explain

Comment: @jasmine There is no reference, I just made it up. Try an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$, take $x_0 =(0,0), x_1 = (1,0)$ and $d = (0,1)$ and plot a few curves for various values of $\alpha$.

Comment: oks now im thinking@copper.hat   $\gamma_\alpha(t) = x_0 + t(x_1-x_0) + \alpha t(1-t) d$

$=(0,0) +t\left((1,0)-(0,0)\right) + \alpha t(1-t)(0,1)=(t,0) +(0,\alpha t(1-t))=(t,\alpha t(1-t))\implies \gamma_\alpha(t)=(t,\alpha t(1-t))$

$\gamma_\alpha(t)= (x(t),y(t))$  where $x(t)=t$  and $y(t)= \alpha t-\alpha t^2$

This mean that in $\gamma_\alpha(t)$ there are uncountably many disjoint curve .Is it correct or not ?

Comment: Well, the argument is a little subtle. For each $\alpha$ there is a range of points $R_\alpha=\{ \gamma_\alpha(t) | 0 < t < 1 \}$ (the end points are all the same which is why I am ignoring them). If $\alpha \neq \alpha'$ then $R_\alpha $ and $R_{\alpha'}$ are disjoint. Since $\alpha$ ranges through $[0,1]$ there are uncountably many of them. Since $A$ is countable, at most a countable number of $R_\alpha$ contain an element of $A$. Hence there are lots of paths that do not pass through $A$.

Comment: @jasmine Sry, forgot to add the @ thing to my response.

Comment: @copper.hat        it oks no problem ,btw thanks u