# Identifying some properties of a set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Let $S \subset R^2$ be defined by

$S$ = {$(m+ \frac{1}{4^{|p|}} , n+ \frac{1}{4^{|q|}}): m,n,p,q \in Z$}

Then,

1. $S$ is discrete in $R^2$.
2. The set of limit points of $S$ is the set {$(m,n) : m,n \in Z$}.
3. $S^c$ is connected but not path connected.
4. $S^c$ is path connected.

This question appeared in CSIR Dec 2015.

I don't have any idea about how to do this question. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint/Solution:**

$(1).$ Note that $(m,n)$ is in $S$ and is also limit point of $S$ hence $S$ is not 
discrete.

$(2).$ Note that elements of the form $(m+ \frac{1}{4^p},n)$ are also  limit points of $S$

$(3,4.)$ [If A is countable then $\mathbb R^2$-$A$ is path connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240453/if-a-subset-mathbbr2-is-countable-is-mathbbr2-setminus-a-path-connec)

Comment: Can you please explain hint for 2 a little more? I am not good at finding limit points.

Comment: Dear @ShivaniGoel Recall that a limit point of a subset $S$ of a topological space $X$ is a point that can be "approximated" by points of $S$.Since we are working in metric space therefore a point $x \in X$ is a limit point iff there is a sequence of elements of $S$ that goes to $x$.So can you find a sequence in $S$ that converges to $(m+ \frac{1}{2^p},n)$?(Hint;For fixed $m,n,p$ consider the sequence  $(m+ \frac{1}{2^p},n+\frac {1}{2^q})$ where does this sequence when $q \to \infty) $

Comment: I was thinking in the same way but I got confused when i saw that if we replace S by the set $S$ = {$(m+ \frac{1}{2^{|p|}} , n+ \frac{1}{2^{|q|}}): m,n,p,q \in Z$} , then the set given in 2) is the set of limit points of new set S. Can you explain this also?

Comment: Yes I am asking for all the limit points of the set S.

Comment: @ShivaniGoel $S$ given in problem or $S$ in your comment?

Comment: S in my comment.

Comment: Note that instead of $4$ in your question you can use any non negative integer greater than $1$.I think all the limit points are $(m,n)$,$(m+ \frac{1}{2^p},n)$ and $(m,n+\frac{1}{2^q})$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40562/discussion-between-shivani-goel-and-arpit-kansal).