# If a continuous function of two variables has finite zero set, then it does not change sign

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=0$ for only finitely many values of $x\in\mathbb R^2$. Can we conclude that $f(x)\leq 0$ or $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: Is $f$ a function $\mathbb{R} \to \Bbb R$ or ${\Bbb R}^2 \to \Bbb R$? If the latter, why does $f$ only take one argument?

Comment: @BruceZheng I think $x$ is meant as a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $f^{-1} \{0\}$ is finite and so $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus f^{-1}  \{0\}$ is connected. Hence $f(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus f^{-1}  \{0\} ) $ is connected, and so must lie completely in either $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$.

**Note**: This is true if $f^{-1} \{0\}$ is countable., see
[Arcwise connected part of $\mathbb R^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155952/27978).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since otherwise there would be two points $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(x_1) < 0 < f(x_2)$. These can be joined by a smooth (or piecewise linear) path $\gamma$ which does not pass through the zeros. This contradicts the intermediate value theorem for $f$ restricted to $\gamma$.