# How well path-connected can a (special) partition of $\Bbb R^2$ be?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

It turned out that [How well connected can a (special) partition of $\Bbb R^2$ be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514720/how-well-connected-can-a-special-partition-of-bbb-r2-be) had a a few nice answers using continum-many pairwise disjoint dense connected sets. Connectedness is just weirder than one first thinks ...

So let's up the ante to path-connectedness:

Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ (where $I=\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Z$; I don't know if it makes a difference - in the linked question the distinction was irrelevant as  solutions with all indices "completely linked" were found even for $I\approx \Bbb R$) such that

- $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i=\Bbb R^2$
- $i\ne j\implies A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$
- $A_i\ne\emptyset$
- $A_i$ is path-connected
- $A_i\cup A_{i+1}$ is path-connected

How often can it happen that $A_i\cup A_j$ is path-connected for $j\notin\{i-1,i,i+1\}$?

**Definition.** Let's say that an index  $n\in I$ is *infinitely linked*/*almost completely linked*/*completely linked* if $A_n\cup A_i$ is path-connected for infinitely many/almost all/all $i\in I$.

One possibility configuration is to let the $A_i$ be vertical stripes, in which case no $n\in I$ is infinitely linked.
With another configuration one can achieve that  there exists exactly one $n\in I$ that is completely linked (let $A_n=\{(0,0)\}$ and all other $A_i$ suitable sectors of $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$).
Can more than that be achieved?

- I.e., are there configurations with more (two, three, arbitrarily many, infinitely many, almost all, all) completely linked indices?
- Or maybe at least more almost completely linked indices?
- For $I=\Bbb Z$, I can find configurations two infinitely linked indices. Are three or more infinitely linked indices possible?
- Are two infinitely linked indices possible with $I=\Bbb N$?

Note that  with $\Bbb R^3$ instead of $\Bbb R^2$ one can easily achieve that all indices are completely linked.

**EDIT:** Only after seeing *Crostul*'s solution (and how it can be adapted for $I=\Bbb Z$, I noticed that it is not possible to have three or more completely linked indices: Pick a point in each of the three sets and a point in each of three other sets. Then we can pick a path witnessing the path-connectedness of the respective unions (wlog.(!) these paths do not intersect) and obtain a solution to the famous gas-water-electricity problem (i.e., a planar embedding of $K_{3,3}$), which is impossible.

Comment: In your edit, how do you get that WLOG the paths do not intersect?

Comment: @EricWofsey First of all, a path in $A_i\cup A_j$ connecting $a\in A_i$ and $b\in A_j$ can be assumed/simplified to transition between the two parts only once (because $A_i,A_j$ are also path-connected). If these transition points are distinct, we need only untangle them within a path-connected set, which should be easy. If two or all three transition points from $A_i$ (we do not consider more paths from $A_i$!) coincide, this transition point must belong to $A_i$ and we may pick it as our vertex.

Comment: It is not obvious to me how you can assume the path transitions only once.   For instance, consider $A_1=[0,1]\times\{0\}\cup (\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1])\times[0,1)$ and $A_2=[0,1]\times\{1\}\cup([0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q})\times(0,1]$.  In this case there does exist a path from $A_1$ to $A_2$ which only transitions once, but it's unclear how you would get such a path by "simplifying" a horizontal path that started at $(0,1/2)$ and ended at $(\alpha,1/2)$ for some irrational $\alpha$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Good point. Seems my adding the "(!)" to the "wlog" was justified :)  So let me try a different approach: Consider paths $\gamma_{ab}\colon[0,1]\to A_a\cup A_b$ from $a\in A_a$ to $b\in A_b$ and $\gamma_{ac}\colon[0,1]\to A_a\cup A_c$ from $a\in A_a$ to $c\in A_c$. Consider $f\colon [0,1]^2\to [0,\infty)$, $(s,t)\mapsto |\gamma_{ab}(s)-\gamma_{ac}(t)|$. This continuous function is positive on the top and the right edge of $[0,1]^2$. By compactness we find a top-right-most $(s_0,t_0)$ with $f(s_0,t_0)=0$. Then $\gamma_{ab}(s_0)=\gamma_{ac}(t_0)$ implies (to be continued)

Comment: (continuation) that $\gamma_{ab}=\gamma_{ac}\in A_a$ and we can take this point instead of $a$. By top-right-most-ness, the chopped paths have no point in common except the start. Together, they form a path from $b$ via $a$ to $c$. Now add a third path $\gamma_{ad}$ in $A_a\cup A_d$. The set of $t\in[0,1]$ where $\gamma_{ad}(t)$ is on one of the other paths is closed and has a maximum $t_1$. We relocate $a$ again to $\gamma_{ad}(t_1)$ and adjust the paths accordingly (note that $\gamma_{ab}\cup \gamma_{ac}$ joins the old and new position of $a$ *within* $A_a$).(to be continued)

Comment: (continued) Note that all adjustments took place within $A_a$ except that possibly some "detour" pieces of paths in $A_b,A_c,A_d$ got chopped away. With the same method we untangle the three paths originating at $b$, then $c$, etc. Fortunately, all vertices in the $K_{3,3}$ we build this way have only degree $3$. -- I hope this sketches a better justification for my "wlog". :)

Comment: I'm almost convinced, but still puzzled by one thing.  When you relocate $a$ to $\gamma_{ad}(t_1)$, let's say that $\gamma_{ad}(t_1)$ also lies on $\gamma_{ab}$.  Then I assume you are redefining $\gamma_{ab}$ to just start at $\gamma_{ad}(t_1)$ instead of the old $a$.  But what do you do with $\gamma_{ac}$?  You could make it start with a path from $\gamma_{ad}(t_1)$ to the old $a$ within $A_a$, but how do you know you can choose such a path that doesn't intersect $\gamma_{ad}$ or $\gamma_{ab}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This picture represents a partition $\{ A_n \}_{n \ge 1}$ with $A_1$ and $A_2$ completely linked.

[image]

Comment: This also works for $I=\Bbb Z$ if we put $A_0, A_{-1},A_{-2},\ldots$ in a similar pattern on the lower side.

Comment: This completely resolves the question regarding *completely* linked as well as *almost completely* linked indices (cf. my edit). Unless someone comes up with interesting insights regarding three or more *inifninitely* linked indices (or maybe even then) your answer deserves to be accepted. Allow me to wait a few hours anyway