# Parametric form of a line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, parametric

I've often seen that a line can be expressed in a parametric form

$x = x_0 + t.( x_1 − x_0 )$

$y = y_0 + t.( y_1 − y0 )$

But I can't see how this makes sense.
Would anyone be able to explain me the meaning of each of these equations?

Comment: Before reading any answers that you get, I suggest that you choose values of the parameters $x_0$, $y_0$, $x_1$, and $y_1$ and plot the resulting points $(x(t),y(t))$ for several values of $t$ to see what you find. Your knowledge gained will be greater by working through this yourself, rather than having someone else do it. Of course, some answers might very well have other insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric equations of a line express the fact that given any three points $P$, $Q$ and $R$ on it, the vectors $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{PR}$ are parallel, i.e.
$$
\vec{PR}=t\cdot\vec{PQ}
$$
for some $t\in\Bbb R$. If you rewrite the displayed equation in terms of the coordinates of $P$ and $Q$ (to be thought "fixed") and $R$ ("variable" or "moving"), you get the parametric equations.

Note that this is valid for a line in ${\Bbb R}^n$ for **any** $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go over the equation of a straight line on $\mathbb R^2$ and not $\mathbb R^3$, because in *3-dimensions* things get a bit more complicated and require you to have understood geometric properties of equations.

First of all, after we assume the *Cartesian System* $(x,y)$, let's start with the simplest equation possible :

$$y - 5 = 0\Leftrightarrow y=5$$

To understand its geometric properties, let's rewrite :

$$y + 0x = 5$$

Now, we can see that $\forall x \in \mathbb R$, $y=5$.

So, that tells us that regardless the number of $x$, the variable $y$ is fixed on a constant number, which means no variations in the form of your geometric object/line.

The constant representation of such an occasion is presented in the $x-y$ *coordinate system* as a straight line, parallel to the $x'x$ axis.

Things get a bit more complicated though, when we have a $2$ *variable equation* with *non-negative* coefficients :

$$x + y + 5 = 0 \Leftrightarrow y = -x-5 $$

Let's observe that for any given $x$, $y$ has a unique value. Thus, every pair of $(x,y$) is unique and can be **dotted** over the $x-y$ *plane*. An infinite "drawing" of these dots, that represent every pair $(x,y)$ that satisfies the equation, will result in a continuous straight line.

Studying the properties of such an equation, is though essential. Let's now assume the general parametric equation :

$$y-y_0 = λ(x-x_0) \Leftrightarrow y =λx - λx_0+y_0$$

Observe that $x,y$ are variables but that $λ,x_0,y_0$ are constant values. Then, our equation could be re-written as :

$$y = λx +C$$

which resembles the form we had in the previous example.

The number $λ\in \mathbb R$ determines the orientation of the line, since as you probably know, from any given point, infinite lines can be crossing it.

The constant value $C\in \mathbb R$ is just a numerical value that determines the position of the line with respect to $(0,0)$. If $C=0$ then the line crosses by $(0,0)$, otherwise not.

Since we are done with explaining the equation of the line and making you understand why it is like that, let's form a more straigh-up mathematical explanation.

Let's assume any three points on the $x-y$ *plane* : $A,B,C$. The parametric equation of the line, expresses the fact that the vectors created with the same starting point $A$ : $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$, are parallel, which in vector calculus is expressed as :

$$\vec{AB} = λ \cdot \vec{AC}$$

for some $λ\in\mathbb R$.

Let's say that : $A=(x_a,y_a),B=(x_b,y_b),C=(x_c,y_c)$. Then the equation above is written as :

$$(x_b - x_a, y_b - y_a) = λ(x_c - x_a, y_c - y_a)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\{x_b - x_a = λ(x_c - x_a),y_b - y_a = λ(y_c - y_a)\}$$

which eventually are, the equations you're asking for.