# If $A$ countable then $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus A$ is path connected

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

> Let $A\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ be countable. I need to prove that
>   $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus A$ is path connected.

I know that through each of $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus A$, there pare uncountably many straight lines, and as there are only countably many points in $A$, uncountably many of these lines will not contain any point of $A$. But why do I construct a path between any two points.

Also can this result be generalised, so that:

> If $X$ is uncountable and $A$ is a countable subset of $X^2$, then
>   should $X^2\setminus A$ be path connected.? (where $X$ and $X^2$ are
>   path connected of course)

Comment: I just can't imagine if $A$ is the set of all rational coordinates, then how one does the continuous path between, say, $(\pi,\pi)$ and $(e,e)$.

Comment: Exactly, but this is a problem from the book on topology by Munkres

Comment: Hint: For $P,Q\in \mathbb{R}^2\backslash A$, consider the straight lines through $P$ and lines through $Q$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155952/arcwise-connected-part-of-mathbb-r2

Comment: @Phil.Z Ok, so there must be a line through $P$ and another line through $Q$ which intersect. Right?

Comment: As @Brian M. Scott has indicated in the link, yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the case of $\Bbb{R}$ was easy to visualise through the concept of lines passing through a point. What about a general case of an uncountable connected space $X$.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha A general uncountable connected space could be disconnected by removing a countable set, indeed even a finite set, indeed even a one-point set.

Comment: Indeed, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is not path-connected.

Comment: Does the context that $X$ is connected, and we are talking about the space $X^2$ make any difference? @LordSharkTheUnknown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let a,b be two points on the plain and not in A.
Draw an arc of a circle of radius r with ab as a cord.
There are uncountable many such arcs and as they are pairwise disjoint execept at the endpoints, almost all of them will miss A. Thus a circlular arc from a to b missing A.

Comment: There are  only two semicircles with  a given diameter. Now, if you were talking about circular arcs....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown.  r is not fixed.

Comment: The radius of a circle is always half its diameter.

Comment: I was going to post a complicated construction but after seeing this, I won't...............+1

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a countable set can only be partitioned into a countable family of blocks. This does not require the Axiom of Choice (just saying).

Exercise 1: Show that there is a line of $\Bbb{R}^2$ wholly contained in $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus A$.

Exercise 2: Choose a line $L_0 \subset \Bbb{R}^2\setminus A$. Show that any point $P \in \Bbb{R}^2\setminus A$ with $P \notin L_0$ belongs to a line $L_P$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ such $L_P \subset \Bbb{R}^2\setminus A$ and $L_P \cap L_0 \ne \emptyset$.